# What does this sentence mean? "Knowledge of the oil industry an asset."

Tags: meaning

My question is about "an asset" in this context, what does it mean? and can one paraphrase the above sentence, so it can be more understandable?

Comment: Please add more context or a link to the original text.

Comment: And here's a link to Workplace Stack Exchange with more info on "assets": https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/92801/do-i-have-to-meet-all-of-the-basic-requirements-plus-the-asset-qualifications-li